# Is this a valid proof for the pythagorean theorem?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, vectors

The Pythagorean theorem states that in a right triangle, $a^2+b^2=c^2$, where $c$ is the hypotenuse. I had this idea for a proof:

Let $a$ and $b$ be orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. We need to prove that

$$\lVert a\rVert^2+\lVert b\rVert^2=\lVert a+b\rVert^2$$

as $a+b$ is the hypotenuse of the right triangle with the other sides $a$ and $b$.

$$\lVert a+b\rVert^2=\langle a+b,a+b\rangle$$

(Definition of the norm)

$$\langle a+b,a+b\rangle=\langle a,a+b\rangle+\langle b,a+b\rangle$$

(Inner product axioms)

$$\langle a,a+b\rangle + \langle b,a+b\rangle=\langle a,a\rangle+\langle a,b\rangle+\langle b,a\rangle+\langle b,b\rangle$$

(Inner product axioms)

$$\langle a,a\rangle+\langle a,b\rangle+\langle b,a\rangle+\langle b,b\rangle=\lVert a\rVert^2+2\langle a,b\rangle+\lVert b\rVert^2$$

(Definition of norm + inner product axioms)

$$\lVert a\rVert^2+2\langle a,b\rangle+\lVert b\rVert^2=\lVert a\rVert^2+\lVert b\rVert^2$$

(The inner product of orthogonal vectors is $0$)

Therefore,

$$\lVert a+b\rVert^2=\lVert a\rVert^2+\lVert b\rVert^2$$

Q.E.D

Is this proof valid?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You can use `\langle` and `\rangle` to get $\langle$ and $\rangle$ instead of using < and >.

Comment: @PeterPhipps Thanks! I started using LaTeX yesterday so I'm not very good at it yet :)

Comment: You're doing fine, I'm just trying to help.

Comment: @PeterPhipps thanks! Sorry if it sounded a bit sarcastic

Comment: This is a classical proof based on the properties of the scalar product. The proof is valid.

Comment: Thanks! aaaaaaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct and is the standard one, but you're being overly clear about what you're doing (you don't need to do everything in really small steps). Indeed it does suffice to just say that if $V$ is a (real or complex) inner product space, and $a,b\in V$ are orthogonal vectors, then

$$\lVert a+b\rVert^2=\langle a+b,a+b\rangle=\langle a,a\rangle+\langle b,b\rangle+\underbrace{\langle a,b\rangle}_{=0}+\underbrace{\langle b,a\rangle}_{=0}=\lVert a\rVert^2+\lVert b\rVert^2$$

(in your case $V=\mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: Thank you!      aaaaaaaa

Comment: @YOH happy to help, feel free to accept the answer :)

Comment: Accepted it. didn't know you could do that haha :)

Comment: The OP proof is overkill for the usual purposes of demonstrating the reasons in a way clear to readers familiar with the concepts. But its form does show a good understanding of the formal proof and makes it safer against overlooking an important assumption or making a mistake by an invalid "shortcut".